# Is there an equivalent to $.getScript that removes or replaces a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am dynamically loading javascript files into an HTML document via $.getScript.  I would like to remove and or replace the old dynamically loaded files variables and functions each time I add a new one.  Is this possible with just jQuery? One of my friends suggested I use Ajax.  Is that necessary, and if so, how would I go about doing so?

Thanks!

(I can provide code if need be, but I don't see why it would be necessary)

Comment: You could probably remove the old file, but you can't *"remove"* scripts that have already ran etc.

Comment: @adeneo If the script had methods and variables will they still be there?  I was under the impression they would.  This is what I want to remove.

Comment: No, no such functionality exists. You'll have to undo whatever the other script did, or reload the page with the new script only.

Comment: @KevinB If I add a new script with functions and or variables with the same name(s) as the old ones, will they overwrite the old functions and or variables?

Comment: maybe, maybe not. depends on how/where they're defined. It won't replace event bindings for example.

Comment: @KevinB  How would definition matter and what types of definitions would work?  (I am newish to javascript, and very new to jQuery)

Comment: for example, if all of the methods are properties of window, replacing them would fix anything that is calling those methods as methods of window, but it wouldn't fix any places where you passed the function reference into another context, such as `$(foo).click(bar)`

Comment: @KevinB Okay, that makes sense, thank you